# JQuery hiding text box?

Tags: jquery

When I click my button, the text box will not hide. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
   $("#butDisplayResults").on("click", function () {
            console.log("butDisplayResults click event 

handler function called!");
            $("#txtInventory").hide();
        });

        $("#txtInventory").hide();
```

Comment: whether the message is getting logged

Comment: Line breaks aren't allowed in strings in Javascript unless you escape them with backslash.

Comment: Can you show us your html code too?

Comment: check your console for any errors

Comment: This appeared: SyntaxError: Using //@ to indicate source map URL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead.
How do I fix that^

Comment: I don't think there is a problem because of this error can you edit your question and add related html part

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this sample code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){      
    $("input#btn").click(function(){
      $("input#txt").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Is your problem get fixed now?

Comment: On the "input#btn" or "input#txt" , do I put in "txtInventory" or do I keep it that way?

Comment: You can use your text box id instead of input#txt so use  $("#txtInventory").hide(); this is right.

Answer (score 0):

Code seems to be correct.
If the message is getting logged then check Id written is correct or not.
Please check that jQuery is correctly added in your html page or not.
And put this code into..

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
/* you code */
});
```

Comment: Thank you, on my code, I have $(docoment).ready(function(){}); except it still will not hide the text boxes when i run it on the browser from Visual Studio :(